# Tool comparable to Windows Paint that would run on Linux

Tags: paint

I have Paint on Windows and I use it for combining images from different files. Say I have several pictures I want to combine into one. Is there any linux application that will do that?

Comment: There is an "equivalent" to Paint called Pinta (get it with `sudo apt install pinta`)

Comment: I am assuming you meant comparable not compatible.  That is, there are *many* compatible tools (just about any that would edit a bitmap file).

Answer (score 1):

You can try [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/).  It is an excellent cross-platform tool.

You will find GIMP on `Ubuntu Software Centre`.

If you want something lighter weight, you can try [Pinta](https://pinta-project.com/pintaproject/pinta/).  It too is available to install through the `Ubuntu Software Centre`.